# Laravel 5.2 cron job running but getting error

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I am using laravel 5.2 in a namecheap shared host. I followed laravel official docs and end up with an error. I tried lot of suggeatios but nothing works. I am using php 7.0.7 and I set register_argc_argv to = On

How can I solve this problem? My cron command

```
php /home/wpbatgag/public_html/torpedo/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```

and here is the error

```
[2016-06-22 08:30:17] local.ERROR: ErrorException: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/wpbatgag/public_html/torpedo/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php:286
Stack trace:
#0 /home/wpbatgag/public_html/torpedo/vendor/symfony/console/Input/ArgvInput.php(286): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleError(2, 'Invalid argumen...', '/home/wpbatgag/...', 286, Array)
#1 /home/wpbatgag/public_html/torpedo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(740): Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput->hasParameterOption(Array, true)
#2 /home/wpbatgag/public_html/torpedo/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(114): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->configureIO(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#3 /home/wpbatgag/public_html/torpedo/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Console/Kernel.php(107): Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#4 /home/wpbatgag/public_html/torpedo/artisan(34): Illuminate\Foundation\Console\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput), Object(Symfony\Component\Console\Output\ConsoleOutput))
#5 {main}
```

Comment: omit this: `1>> /dev/null 2>&1` and try.

Comment: Already did. But the error is same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use php-cli:

```
php-cli -q /path/to/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Instead of php:

```
php /path/to/artisan schedule:run 1>> /dev/null 2>&1
```